# Android: ProgressDialog crashes when use resources to initialize the message

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

When I use this code:

```
public class VideoSorveglianza extends Activity {

  private ProgressDialog mLoading;

      ...

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      ...

      mLoading = new ProgressDialog(this);
      mLoading.setMessage("Loading");
      ...
}
```

All works fine. But If I try this:

```
mLoading.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
```

with the string declared in res/string.xml, nothing works!

Is this a bug? I use API version 2.2.

EDIT: my string.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
...
<string name="loading">Loading...</string>
...
</resources>
```

Comment: try clean & re-build, it should work (unless you have some typo) you might want to share your string.xml as well.

Comment: Post the log for this if you are getting any error.

Comment: Where is your strings.xml saved? I have had issues where I was providing multiple values folders (values-en values-fr) and forgot to include the string in the folder that matched the language the android device was reporting. Make sure you at least provide the string in the default values/strings.xml.

Comment: MByD was right... A clean was enough...

Answer (score 10):

Use `getResources().getString(R.string.loading)`
in `mLoading.setMessage()`